# Searching arraylist and comparing strings

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, boolean

I am working on a java app that takes scanner string inputs from the user and compares two strings attributes. The goal is for the method to be a username and password authentication. The code compiles but it only seems to cycle through the first row in the ArrayList.

```
//function to authenticate login credentials
    private void login() {
        int i = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");
        String login = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        String pswd = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("ArrayList size = " + arrayList.size());
        System.out.println("Position being checked: " + i);

        while (!foundIt == true) {

            if (login.equals(arrayList.get(i).getUsername()) && pswd.equals(arrayList.get(i).getPassword())) {
                currentUser = (login);
                loggedInBanner();
                foundIt = true;
            } //else (!login.equals(arrayList.get(i).getUsername()) && !pswd.equals(arrayList.get(i).getPassword())) {
            //System.out.println("The username and/or password did not match. Try agin.");
            else if (i < arrayList.size()) {
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("The account does not exist.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but it only seems to cycle through the first row` -- You are aware that your print statement about the position being checked isn't inside the loop, right?  It can only ever print once...

Comment: The loop looks to be incrementing correctly.  You can move the "Position being checked" print out into the loop to get a better idea of the progress.

Comment: on top of what @azurefrog stated, I also think checking `while(!foundIt == true)` is very hard to interpret quickly. Why not do `while(foundIt == false)`?

Comment: hand palm to face....thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: Or even better, `while (!foundIt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using for-each loop

You are just making it more complex. Assuming that your goal was to find the user in an ArrayList matching the provided credentials, you can use a for-each loop to make it easier.

```
for (User user : users)
```

- `users` is an `ArrayList` type here.
- Each user is an `User` object. (I'm really assuming this type here, as you've not provided yours in the question.)

Then just compare with the provided credentials and when matched, terminate the loop.

```
if (user.getUserName().equals(userName) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
{
    loggedInUser = user;
    break;
}
```

That is all there is to it.

## Using while loop

By the way, it appears to be a homework question isn't it? In case you must use the while loop, here is how:

- Loop while the user isn't found.
- If the user is found break the loop.
- If the iterating index is greater than the arraylist size, break.

Turning that into code, it looks like this:

```
User loggedInUser = null;

boolean found = false;
int index = 0;

while (!found)
{
    if (index >= users.size())
        break;

    User user = users.get(index++);

    if (user.getUserName().equals(userName) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
    {
        loggedInUser = user;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

So far, good, but we can even make it shorter, and remove the found boolean variable, and use the index directly there.

```
int index = -1;
while (++index < users.size())
{
    User user = users.get(index);

    if (user.getUserName().equals(userName) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
    {
        loggedInUser = user;
        break;
    }
}
```

## Using the Java 8 way

```
User loggedInUser = users.stream()
     .filter(u -> u.getUserName().equals(userName))
     .filter(u -> u.getPassword().equals(password))
     .findFirst()
     .orElse((User) null);
```

Hope this helps.